# unknown SET option beginning "oracle_sid..."

Tags: oracle

```
SQL> set oracle_sid=sid
SP2-0735: unknown SET option beginning "oracle_sid..."
SQL> emctl start dbconsole;
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "emctl star..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> set oracle_sid=sid emctl start dbconsole;
SP2-0735: unknown SET option beginning "oracle_sid..."
SQL> SQL> set oracle_sid=sid
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "SQL> set o..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> SP2-0735: unknown SET option beginning "oracle_sid...
```

why this service is invoked??can you tell that?

Answer (score 8):

These commands should be run from the OS command line not the SQL prompt.

Comment: Note that the ORACLE_SID in Linux is case sensitive, and you should also run ". oraenv" (on linux) to pick up all the correct variables for the different instance.